# What is the formula to count number of passes of a list items if cycled x times

Tags: python, algorithm, math, python-itertools, discrete-mathematics

Given

```
    list =['a','b','c']
```

How to get number of times an item gets accessed when cycling the list x times. For example:

```
    # if we cycled list 4 times, output would be
    output = [('a',2), ('b',1), ('c',1)]

    # if we cycled list 7 times, output would be
    output = [('a',3), ('b',2), ('c',2)]
```

Is there a formula for this, or a loop is necessary?

Comment: Hint: say you make 7 "hops", what is the number of visits for each item?

Comment: and yes, there is a "logic" for this, that does not require looping.

Comment: `output = [('a',3), ('b',3), ('c',1)]` is wrong for 7... Just divide the no. of times by the length of the list and look at the quotient and the remainder which you can get using `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times we visit the *k*-th item in a list with *n* items, and *v* visits is ⌈(v-k)/n⌉, which is equivalent to ⌊(v-k+n-1)/n⌋. After all we make *v* visits, so that means each item has at least ⌊v/n-1⌋ visits. The last "round" distributes the remaining *v - ⌊v/n-1⌋*, and the first *v - ⌊v/n-1⌋* items "retrieve" a visit.

We can generate such list in linear time with:

```
def visit_count(data, v):
    n = len(data)
    return [(x, (v-i+n-1)//n) for i, x in enumerate(data)]
```

For example:

```
>>> visit_count('abc', 7)
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
>>> visit_count('abc', 8)
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]
>>> visit_count('abc', 9)
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
>>> visit_count('abc', 10)
[('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
```

Since this runs in the length of the list, and not in the number of visits, it means that we can solve this problem for reasonable lists, and a huge number of visits. For example:

```
>>> visit_count('abcde', 1_234_567_890_123_456)
[('a', 246913578024692), ('b', 246913578024691), ('c', 246913578024691), ('d', 246913578024691), ('e', 246913578024691)]
```

Doing the bookkeeping for 1'234'567'890'123'456 visits individually would result in the function taking ages to obtain the result. But since the number of elements (here 5) is limited, it takes only a few microseconds.

Comment: (v-i+n-1)//n is what I was looking for. Thank you sir !

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate this partially, but a loop is needed at some point for this approach. Use floor division to find how many complete passes are made, then increment the rest by 1 (starting from the left) for the remainder - incomplete passes:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cycles = 7
complete_passes, remainder = divmod(cycles, len(data))
passes = {i: complete_passes for i in data}
for key in data[:remainder]:
    passes[key] += 1
```

*Note on `divmod`:*

```
divmod(x, y)
```

...returns...

```
(x//y, x%y)
# floor division, modulus
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best approach but you might still find it useful. The idea is to find have the extended list and then use `Counter` to get the occurrence frequency

```
from collections import Counter

n = 7
listt = ['a','b','c']

a = n%len(listt) 
b = int(n/len(listt))

listt = listt*b + listt[0:a]
result = [(i, j) for i,j in Counter(listt).items()]
print (result)
# [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply divide the length of the list by the number of loops, and add 1 for the elements whose index is less than the remainder:

```
def nb_accesses(sequence, loops):
    length = len(sequence)
    out = [(value, loops // length + (index < loops % length))
            for index, value in enumerate(sequence)]
    return out

sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(nb_accesses(sequence, loops=0))
# [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)]

print(nb_accesses(sequence, loops=3))
# [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]

print(nb_accesses(sequence, loops=5))
# [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

`index < loops % length` evaluates to 0 (False) or 1 (True).

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
import itertools as it
import collections as ct


lst = list("abc")
n = 7
```

**Code**

```
iterable = (it.islice(it.cycle(lst),  n)
[(k, v) for k, v in ct.Counter(iterable).items()]
# [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```